bitbucket pipeline scp deployment SSH fails
I am trying to build and deploy my react.js app to a server, which has SSH on port 9500. This is the first time I have done this. In Repository settings, Pipelines, I have added my keypair and my known hosts. I have verified (from Windows, in multiple apps and in command prompt) that my keypair works, without password.
Here is my script:
image: node:16  # Use a Node.js Docker image

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and Deploy
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - npm install  # Install dependencies
          - npm run build  # Build the React app
          - scp -P 9500 -r ./build/* myusername@myserver.com:/home/myusername/songs/songstest  # Deploy to server

The run build works fine, but it fails on the upload via SCP with error "Host key verification failed."
I've tried various combinations of this, without success, including debugging steps.
image: node:16  # Use a Node.js Docker image (you can change the version as needed)

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and Deploy
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - mkdir -p ~/.ssh  # Create .ssh directory if it doesn't exist
          - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa  # Store the private key
          - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa  # Set correct permissions for the private key
          - ssh-keyscan -p 9500 myserver.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
          - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts  # Ensure known_hosts permissions are correct
          - cat ~/.ssh/known_hosts  # Debugging: output the known_hosts file to check if the server's key is added
          - ssh -p 9500 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa myusername@myserver.com "echo 'SSH Connection Successful'"  # Test the SSH connection before starting
          - npm install  # Install dependencies
          - npm run build  # Build the React app
          - scp -P 9500 -r ./build/* myusername@myserver.com:/home/myusername/songs/songstest  # Deploy to server

When I do not add the known host in my script, it still shows up when I cat known_hosts, because I already added it in Bitbucket's repository settings.
I suspect that most of the above code is unnecessary. Bitbucket's documentation does not address how to troubleshoot an SSH connection failure, nor exactly how to set it up.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Have you tried adding it in BitBucket repos known hosts?

Yes, I've added both the domain and the IP address to known hosts. Also confirmed by echoing known hosts that they are there.

you should try ssh with -VVVVV. Also setup the ssh keys in Bitbucket repo settings instead
